# Using limited natural deduction rules to prove de morgan's law

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am trying to prove something reversely, but always get stuck when it comes to $\neg r\wedge \neg q\vdash \neg (r\vee q)$.

How can I prove it using the following rules?

[image]

Here's where I get stucked.
[image]

Comment: Don't you really have any rule for the introduction of $\lnot$? Without it, the solution is quite clumsy.

Comment: No $\neg$-introduction is explicitly banned...

Comment: Assume $(r \lor q)$ and use $(\lor \text E)$ deriving $\bot$ in both sub-poorfs. Then conclude by $(\to \text I)$.

Comment: That's something I have tried, but in the system I am taught, there's no $\bot$, so I want to find an alternative.

Comment: A general remark on having no $\bot$: if you have any proposition $p$ at all, then you should be able to use $p\wedge\neg p$ in place of $\bot$. (That's essentially what I did in the version of $\neg$-introduction in my answer; a pure $\neg$-introduction rule would just be $\to$-introduction where $\neg A$ is $A\to\bot$, but since I didn't have $\bot$, I interpreted $\neg A$ as $A\to(B\wedge\neg B)$ instead, passed the resulting rule through $\wedge$-introduction so it wouldn't have to explictly refer to $\wedge$, and only *then* noticed that it looked just like the $\neg$-elimination rule.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not particularly fond of this list of rules, because $ \neg $-introduction is missing.  Normally I say, eliminate what you have and introduce what you want, but how can you do that when you want $ \neg $ and there is no introduction rule for that!?

So first, here is the introduction rule for $ \neg $:

> If $ \Sigma , A \vdash B $ and $ \Sigma , A \vdash \neg B $ are theorems, then so is $ \Sigma \vdash \neg A $.

(It looks a lot like the elimination rule!  But whereas that rule (3) is fundamentally about eliminating the $ \neg $ on $ \neg B $, this rule is fundamentally about introducing the $ \neg $ on $ \neg A $.)

Now, you can't use this in your assignment (assuming that you're doing an assignment), because it's not on your list.  But the reason that they can leave it off the list is because it can be proved from the rules on the list!

First, we must prove the double-negation theorem $ \neg \neg A \vdash A $.  First, notice that $ \neg \neg A \vdash \neg \neg A $ by reflexivity (1) and so $ \neg A , \neg \neg A \vdash \neg \neg A $ by addition (2).  Similarly, $ \neg A \vdash \neg A $ by reflexivity, and so $ \neg A , \neg \neg A \vdash \neg A $ by addition.  Now (3) applies (with $ \neg \neg A $ for $ \Sigma $ and $ \neg A $ for $ B $) and conclude that $ \neg \neg A \vdash A $.

Now we can prove the $\neg$-introduction rule.  So suppose that $ \Sigma , A \vdash B $ and $ \Sigma , A \vdash \neg B $.  Then by $ \to $-introduction (5), $ \Sigma \vdash A \to B $ and $ \Sigma \vdash A \to \neg B $.  By addition, also $ \Sigma , \neg \neg A \vdash A \to B $ and $ \Sigma , \neg \neg A \vdash A \to \neg B $.  But also, by applying addition to the double-negation rule proved in the last paragraph, $ \Sigma , \neg \neg A \vdash A $.  So by $ \to $-elimination (6), $ \Sigma , \neg \neg A \vdash B $ and $ \Sigma , \neg \neg A \vdash \neg B $.  Then by $ \neg $-elimination, $ \Sigma \vdash \neg A $.

Now you can use $ \neg $-introduction even though it wasn't on your list!

Comment: Thank you for showing $\neg$-introduction is provable by the rules. But I just notice that in the two statements I want to prove (updated in the question description), $\neg a \wedge \neg b$ is on the RHS. Is it possible to prove $\neg(a\vee b)$ also on the RHS? Or should I take other approaches?

Comment: @KOMAX233 Well, the two theorems that you're trying to prove do have shorter proofs, with less application of $\neg$-elimination and more application of $\vee$-elimination, so for that reason perhaps you should take a different approach. Still, it is a theorem that $\neg r\wedge\neg q\vdash\neg(r\vee q)$, so it's fair to try to prove that even if you don't need it for these two problems. And if you're willing to use the now-proved rule for $\neg$-introduction, then you can do this by showing that $\neg r,\neg q,r\vee q\vdash q$ (using $\vee$-elimination) and $\neg r,\neg q,r\vee q\vdash\neg q$

Comment: @KOMAX233 Maybe the common theme to all of this is that you should try to use $\vee$-elimination more! ☺️